# Python: Are dictionaries declared in methods global?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

So in of my methods under a class I created a dictionary with many keys and its contents.
I want to use it in another function, and I was wondering if dictionaries created in one method are global, and can be used  in another dictionary.

If it it not global, I would also like to know if there is a way to make them global.

Comment: global variables are almost never the answer.

Comment: Is the other function also part of the same class? You _can_ make things global but it's almost never what you want to do.

Comment: Are you talking about a class member dictionary? A module level dictionary?

Comment: Just define a dictionary, pass it to `f`, make `f` return the new dictionary, pass that on to `g`. Global mutable variables can be a nightmare to debug, usually don't behave the way you expect them to, and I wouldn't recommend using them, unless it's some static data that you never modify. Alternatively you could define a class, make the dictionary a member of that class, and access it from all functions using `self.d`

Answer (score 1):

By default, dictionaries (or any variable) declared in methods are not global. They are contained within the scope of the method.

I wrote a test script that proves it. **global_test.py**:

```
def test():
    myDict = {
        "key1" : "value1"
    }
    print "Inside method " + myDict["key1"]
test()
#Try calling dictionary created in test() method:
print "Outside method" + myDict["key1"]
```

**Running script:** >python global_test.py

```
Inside method value1
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "global_test.py", line 11, in <module>
        print "Outside method" + myDict["key1"]
NameError: name 'myDict' is not defined
```

As others have eluded, global variables are almost never the right way to solve a problem.